# would or used to for habits

Tags: modal-verbs

From the ELL SE post [am I a native speaker?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128623/am-i-a-native-speaker)

> So I literally grew up with their kids and they taught me English and my brother and I **would** teach them Portuguese (I'm Brazilian btw)

After reading the differences between used to and would when talkng about habits on the bbc web, I think used to would be more appropriate as teaching is not something you do many times Once the learner speaks fluently is finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Would* is fine in this context because the time frame has been established as being in the past. *Used to* can still be used here, but *would* sounds more natural in this instance. It's only when you remove the time frame that *would* no longer makes sense. Compare these sentences:

> Do you see those kids? I would teach them English.

This means that you would teach them English if you had the opportunity.

> Do you see those kids? I used to teach them English.

This means that in the past you taught them English.

However, once you insert a phrase establishing the time frame being in the past, the first sentence can be made to mean the same as the second.

> Do you see those kids? **They grew up around the corner from me.** I would teach them English.